# newbie about regular expression in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code to match pattern from str

```
match = re.search(r'word:\w\w\w', str)
```

I try to create a variable

```
pat='word:\w\w\w' # and using in re.search 
match = re.search(rpat, str)
```

I got compile error

how to create a variable for a pattern in Python?

Comment: You forgot the `r` before the regex string in the second example. You need it to make the `\` not act as escape character.

Comment: You have `pat` and `rpat`

Comment: Also, this will help you to test out some more regex: http://pythex.org

Comment: You are passing a type i.e `str` which is causing the error

Comment: Please provide a stack trace and a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You can't replace `r'word:\w\w\w'` by erasing the string and adding a variable name in front of the `r`. The `r` is part of the string literal, so it has to go with you when you move it.

```
pat=r'word:\w\w\w'
match = re.search(pat, str)
```

Although in this particular situation, you don't need the `r` at all, since your string doesn't have any escape sequences in it anyway.

```
pat='word:\w\w\w'
match = re.search(pat, str)
```

Comment: I think the error is `str` not the pattern, `pat='word:\w\w\w'` would not cause a compile error

Comment: It has to be as you don't need `r`, using pat with or without r will not cause an error

Comment: Hmm, I'd expect using `rpat` instead of `pat` to give a NameError, and using `str` instead of an actual string to give a `TypeError`. I don't know what would cause a CompileError.

Comment: Yes, a TypeError but the OP would see `_compile(pattern, flags).search(string)` so that may be what they are referring to

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. I hope OP will return and clear things up with a stack trace.

Comment: Yep, just posting the stack trace alone actually would have been more informative than the current question.